# How to append data from a class to a struct? Throws expected declaration

Tags: arrays, dictionary, struct, swift3

I am defining a dictionary with the values as an array. The values (inside the array) is obtained from another function and defined through JSONSerialization in a class. I need the values to be passed down to a struct (so it can be accessed globally, related to my other post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40180767/access-value-of-variables-from-other-classes ). However, it doesn't seem to behave as a normal dictionary.

This is the whole piece of code of that particular swift file, including the class and the struct. Any help is appreciated thanks.

edit: shows where is the error

```
struct busStopIdentities
{

static var busStopArray : [String : [AnyObject]] = ["busStopCode_as_identifier" : ["busStopData" as AnyObject]]

}

class BusStop
{

var busStopCode : String?
var roadName : String?
var busStopDescription : String?
var busStopLatitude : Double?
var busStopLongitude : Double?

init(jsonDataDictiony : [String : AnyObject])
{

    //print(jsonDataDictiony)

    if let valueArray = jsonDataDictiony["value"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]
    {

        for valueDictionary in valueArray
        {

            self.busStopCode = valueDictionary["BusStopCode"] as? String
            self.roadName = valueDictionary["RoadName"] as? String
            self.busStopDescription = valueDictionary["Description"] as? String
            self.busStopLatitude = valueDictionary["Latitude"] as? Double
            self.busStopLongitude = valueDictionary["Longitude"] as? Double

        }

    }

}

busStopIdentities.busStopArray[busStopCode] = [busStopCode, roadName, busStopDescription, busStopLatitude, busStopLongitude]
^ expected declaration

}
```

Comment: access busStopArray as  busStopIdentities.busStopArray inside BusStop class.

Comment: Its still throws the same error under busStopIdentities @Anish웃

Comment: put busStopIdentities.busStopArray..... inside a method.For now test by putting inside init() method

Comment: Currently its error free thanks, will tell you about the progress

Answer (score -1):

A struct is not an object is a datetype, you have to create a variable, and assign to that datetype, like

var busS = 
    busStopIdentities(busStopArray[busStopCode]: [busStopCode, roadName, busStopDescription, busStopLatitude, busStopLongitude])

I don't know swift, so the sintax may be wrong.